# as.Date in for loop performing unexpectedly

Tags: r, for-loop, coercion

Why does this (admittedly unorthodox) use of `as.Date` within a for loop produce unexpected results?

I have the following date vector:

```
df.1 <- c("30-Sep-12", "30-Nov-12", "30-Sep-12", 
  "30-Nov-12", "30-Sep-12", "30-Nov-12", 
  "30-Sep-12")
```

Now of course to get them in the standard date format, I can use

```
df.date <- as.Date(df.1, format="%d-%b-%y")
```

But in the context of my script I wanted to use a `for` loop:

```
as.Date(df.1[6], format="%d-%b-%y")  # "30-Sep-12"
# [1] 2012-11-30  # as expected

df.for <- df.1
for (i in seq_along(df.1)){
df.for[i] <- as.Date(df.1[i], format="%d-%b-%y")
}
df.for[6]
# [1] 15674  # unexpected
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single atomic vector can only be of a single class

When you use `[<-` to replace a single value of `df.for`, `R` can't hold those values you have not changed as "character" variables that look like Dates, and a Date class value (a number which is formated and displayed like a character). Therefore it coerces to character.

you could get around this by making `df.for` a `list`

eg

```
df.for <- as.list(df.1)
for (i in seq_along(df.1)){
  df.for[[i]] <- as.Date(df.1[i], format="%d-%b-%y")
}
```

Or by coercing the results back to  a Date at the end of the loop (via numeric)

eg

```
df.for <- df.1
for (i in seq_along(df.1)){
  df.for[i] <- as.Date(df.1[i], format="%d-%b-%y")
}

as.Date(as.numeric(df.for),origin = '1970-01-01')
```