# `as.Date` performance changes when wrapped

Tags: r, date, types

I'm puzzled by my example below. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17562264/8400969) might contain the key for me, but I'm missing it. When I run `as.Date("1900-01-01")` **R** prints something that looks just like the input:

```
> as.Date("1920-01-01")
[1] "1920-01-01"
```

I had hoped to check that inputs were "Dates" and coerce them to be if they were `character`, and so I wrote this very simple function to learn what was going on

```
check_date <- function(x){
  ifelse(class(x)=="Date"
                       , x
                       , as.Date(x))
}
```

But now it seems like I'm getting a `numeric` value back out:

```
cdOut <- check_date("1920-01-01")
> cdOut
[1] -18263
```

What is happening here?

Comment: This is an annoying vagary of `ifelse`, see a [complete explanation here with general alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/903061).

Comment: I would say, this particular case is a good example of where you should be using `if()`, not `ifelse()`. `ifelse()` is designed for working with vectors and modifying parts of them. When you have a length 1 condition, `if(){}else{}` should be preferred. `if(class(x) != "Date") {x <- as.Date(x)} return(x)` would be a more appropriate function body.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Thanks, both comments are perfect!

Comment: I'd also mention that `class(x) ==` is a bad way to check class, because objects in R can have multiple classes. This is why many classes have a `is.class()` function. There is no `is.Date()`, so `if(inherits(x, "Date"))` would be good. (Though with `Date` class this isn't likely to cause problems... just general best practice.)